# Replacing two string using sed in Python: sed: -e expression #1, char 117: unterminated `s' command

Tags: python, sed

My command in as follows:

```
import re
import subprocess
def replace(t1,t2):
   print(t1,t2)
   #output: oldtxt,newtxt
   cmd="sed -i -r 's,%s,%s,' test.conf"%(t1,t2)
   print(cmd)
   subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
   print ("done!")
```

ERROR:

```
sed -i -r 's,oldtxt,    newtxt

,' test.conf
sed: -e expression #1, char 117: unterminated `s' command

done!
```

I have also tried this command:

```
cmd="sed -i -r 's/{}/{}/' test.conf".format(t1,t2)
```

I still get the same error.
I know there are some questions with similar topic but their answers weren't helpful for this case.

Besides, how to replace t2 with every string which includes t1?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED:

test.conf includes:

```
....

proxy_path      http://oldtxtabcs1234:5000/

....
```

I want to replace it with newtxt like:

```
....

proxy_path      newtxt

....
```

Comment: I think the error is due to newlines in t2

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks, it helped. The problem that I have now is that, I want to replace t2 with every text which starts with t1. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: would be useful if you can add sample text along with expected output and how current output is wrong... I think probably you are looking for `g` flag without which sed replaces only first occurrence in a line... also, any particular reason you are using sed instead of doing it all in python?

Comment: @Sundeep I've edited my question. Please check it. Well, I don't have any specific reason to use sed cmd. I just want to do the replacement process properly. And as I've started using python recently, I'm not that much familiar with different solutions.

Comment: Why don't you do the search and replace **in** Python? There's no need to call out to sed to do this. Your code will be a lot less fragile and more portable. Eg. `open('test.conf', 'w').write(open('test.conf', 'r').read().replace('http://oldtxtabcs1234:5000/', 'newtxt'))`

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thanks I'll try it.